# else if Unexpected token else

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error

I have a weird syntax issue. I receive the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

Code, that is related to that issue:

```
if (j <= 9) {
  nameUs[i].className += ' selected-country';
  pointUs[i].className += ' selected-country';

  for (k = 1; k < imageTime.length+1; ++k) {
    $('#avatar-'+[j]+' .img-car-'+[k]+'').attr('href','cars/car-'+[k]+'.png');

    $('#backgrounds .background-'+[j]).show();
    pushPercent.push(percentHere);
    if (j == 1) {
      $('.'+$.cookie('original-class')).addClass('selected');
      $('.'+pinnedIncentive).addClass('selected');

      if (pinnedIncentive == 'kpis' ) {
        $('.mm-flag .flag-text').html('300€');
        $('.mm-flag .flag-text').css('font-size','72px');
        $('.mm-flag .flag-text').css('line-height','60px');
      }

    }
    if (j == 9) {
      nameUs[i].className += ' last-one';
    }
  } else if (j > 9 && j <= 19) {
    nameUs[i].className += ' selected-country right-sided last-one';
    pointUs[i].className += ' selected-country right-sided last-one';
    $(pointUs[i]).css('padding-top',233*([j]-10)+'px');
    $(nameUs[i]).css('padding-top',233*([j]-10)+'px');
    $('#backgrounds-right .background-'+[j]).show();

    if (j == 9) {
      nameUs[i].className += ' last-one';
    }
  }
  j++;
}
```

Could anybody give me a clue on how to solve that? It is the first time that I face this weird error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you got a `;` after your `if {}` block before the `else` you've given here?

Comment: This code is fine (syntactically), but probably not correct in combination with the code before the `else`. That has to be either an `if` with a single statement, or an `if`  with a compound statement (code block within `{ 
 } `.

Comment: BTW: how can this be at the same time? `j > 9` and `j=9`

Comment: Thank you. Missed closing tag. Friday....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Pastebin link you posted, you forgot to close your `for` loop here:

```
if (j <= 9) {
        nameUs[i].className += ' selected-country';
        pointUs[i].className += ' selected-country';

        for (k = 1; k < imageTime.length+1; ++k) { <---
            $('#avatar-'+[j]+' .img-car-'+[k]+'').attr('href','cars/car-'+[k]+'.png');

        ****HERE******

        $('#backgrounds .background-'+[j]).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

When correcting your indentation, I noticed `else if` is attached to your for loop :

```
  for (k = 1; k < imageTime.length+1; ++k) {
    $('#avatar-'+[j]+' .img-car-'+[k]+'').attr('href','cars/car-'+[k]+'.png');

    $('#backgrounds .background-'+[j]).show();
    pushPercent.push(percentHere);
    if (j == 1) {
      $('.'+$.cookie('original-class')).addClass('selected');
      $('.'+pinnedIncentive).addClass('selected');

      if (pinnedIncentive == 'kpis' ) {
        $('.mm-flag .flag-text').html('300€');
        $('.mm-flag .flag-text').css('font-size','72px');
        $('.mm-flag .flag-text').css('line-height','60px');
      }

    }
    if (j == 9) {
      nameUs[i].className += ' last-one';
    }
  } else if (j > 9 && j <= 19) {
```

Fix the for loop here :

```
for (k = 1; k < imageTime.length+1; ++k) {
  $('#avatar-'+[j]+' .img-car-'+[k]+'').attr('href','cars/car-'+[k]+'.png');
}
```

and fix the `else if` here :

```
if (j == 9) {
  nameUs[i].className += ' last-one';
} else if (j > 9 && j <= 19) {
```